# ASP.NET 3.5 Stops responding

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

A client has complained about some legacy code that was written a while back.  When the client uploads a file, the server takes the file and processes it.  This is using the Script Services (Web Service).  It appears that the file takes ~10 minutes to finish and when it does, it responds back saying it finished.  Unfortunately, I am getting no message on the browser side of either success or failure.  I can see that the function finished, but the browser receives no notification of this event.  I will be more than happy to provide more information as needed.

Thanks!

Comment: To add to this, Fiddler reports the same thing the browser does.  Fiddler does not see a message coming back from the server.  This is for Chrome and IE 9

Comment: Is it an ajax call on a webpage, or a webservice that is accessed directly?  What is the return from the function, JSON? or HTML?

Comment: It is an ajax call using the Script Manager provided by the ASP.NET Ajax Control Tookit.  The return is a plain string as far as the service is concerned.  It is actually a file name.

Comment: At what point does the ajax call complete?  Can you tell? I'm assuming that if no response is ever received that firebug console will show the call as open?

Comment: Correct.  From what I can tell, it appears to be something on our router.  The timeout for TCP connections is 300 seconds and therefore the 10 minute connection with no communication seems to exceed that.

Comment: There are ways to implement ajax keepalives etc.  If the process takes that long, you are almost better to send the request for process, and then query to see if it is done and return at that point. (2 seperate calls).  Are you able to change the code?  The webservice will also have an "open call" timeout (at least WCF does).  You might want to try fiddling with those options.

Comment: @Terry let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2820/discussion-between-ctrldot-and-terry)